# Direct3D find 2D screen coordinate works but mirrored glitch when stressed

Tags: c++, 3d, directx, directx-11, direct3d

I have this function to get a 2D pixel location from 3D coordinate position. The x y z are pre-transform coordinates (1 to -1).  This is a model view architecture with camera permanently at -3.5,0,0 looking at 0,0,0 while the object/scenes 
coordinates are transformed by a horizontal xz rotation and vertical y rotation, etc to produce the final frame.

This function is mostly used to overlay 2D text on top of the 3D scene. Where the 2D text is positioned relative to the 3D underlying scene.

```
void My3D::Get2Dfrom3Dx(float x, float y, float z, float* psx, float* psy)  {

    XMVECTOR xmScreenCoord = XMLoadFloat3( (XMFLOAT3*) &screenCoord);
    XMMATRIX xmWorldViewProjection = XMLoadFloat4x4( (XMFLOAT4X4*) &m_WorldViewProjection);
    XMVECTOR result = XMVector3TransformCoord( xmScreenCoord, xmWorldViewProjection);
    XMStoreFloat3( (XMFLOAT3*) &screenCoord, result);

    screenCoord.x = ((screenCoord.x + 1.0f) / 2.0f) * m_nCurrWidth;
    screenCoord.y = ((-screenCoord.y + 1.0f) / 2.0f) * m_nCurrHeight;

*psx = screenCoord.x;
*psy = screenCoord.y; }
```

This function works perfectly when the scene is fully/mostly visible, (the eyeat between -4 and -1.5.)

I have a nagging problem with text showing up mirrored in 3D position where it should not be.
This happens when for example I'm viewing the image from below (60+ degrees upward below object), and zooming(moving the eyeat location closer to say -.5,0,0.)  The text should not be visible as it should be behind the eye (note eyeat is not past 0,0,0 which really messes the image up), 
but somehow the above function causes the calculated screen x y coordinates to show within the viewport in situations where they should not.

I seem to think there is a simple solution to this side effect but can't find it.  Hopefully someone has seen this 2d mirrored problem/effect before and knows the simple tweak.

I realize I could go down a more complex path of determining if the view vector is opposite the target point and filter this way, but I seem to think there should be a simpler solution.

Again, the camera is permanently on the line -3.5, 0, 0 to say -.5,0,0 as the world is transformed around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the way the projection works. Basically, the perspective projection will divide the x and y coordinates by the z coordinate. That's how you get the effect of perspective, i.e., that things that are farther away (larger z coordinate) appear smaller on screen. One issue with this perspective division is (simplified) that it doesn't work correctly for stuff that's behind the camera. Stuff behind the camera will have a negative z coordinate. When you divide x and y by a negative value, you'll have your point reflected around the origin. Which is exactly what you see. Since stuff that's located behind the camera is not going to be visible anyways, one way to solve this problem is to simply clip all geometry before dividing by z such that everything that has a negative z value is cut off and removed.

I assume the division in your code here happens inside `XMVector3TransformCoord()`. As you note yourself, the text should not be visible in the problematic cases anyways. So I suggest you simply check whether the text is behind the camera and don't render it if it is. One way to do so would be to simply check the result of transforming your world-space position with the `xmWorldViewProjection` matrix and only continue if it happens to be in front of the camera. `xmScreenCoord` holds the homogeneous clipspace coordinates of your point. The point will be in front of the camera iff the z coordinate of `xmScreenCoord` is larger than zero. So I guess you'd want to do something like

```
if (XMVectorGetZ(xmScreenCoord) > 0)
{
    …
}
```

Sidenote due to the discussion in the comments below: When one wants to solve a problem involving the projections of objects on screen, one can often avoid explicitly computing the projection by instead transforming the problem into its dual and working directly in projective space on homogeneous coordinates. Since your problem is about placing text in 2D on screen, however, I don't think this is an option here. You could place the geometry for drawing your text in clip-space directly. You would start again by computing the clip-space coordinates of the 3D point to which you want your 2D text attached (by multiplying them with `m_WorldViewProjection` but not dividing by w). You can then generate homogeneous coordinates for the geometry for drawing your text by simply offsetting the x- and y- coordinates from that point to get the corners of a quad or whatever you need to construct. If you then also scale the size of the quad by the w coordinate of the point, you will get a quad at that position that projects to always the same size on the screen (since the premultiplication with w effectively cancels out the projection). However, all you're effectively doing then is leaving the application of the projection and necessarily clipping to the GPU. If you want to render a large number of quads, that might be an option to consider as it could be done completely on the GPU, e.g., using a geometry shader. However, if you just have a few text elements, it would be much simpler and probably also more efficient to just skip the drawing of text elements that would be behind the camera as described above…

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Ya, what you are saying is absolutely correct.  I've been studying https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/computing-pixel-coordinates-of-3d-point/mathematics-computing-2d-coordinates-of-3d-points   which discusses the issue and my testing the z value, TRACEing it to see if I can perceive the math that was happening has not helped. My gut says the full World View Projection transform is the issue but not sure how to move forward.  I was thinking maybe a WorldView matrix before the projection, and then doing a manual projection may help but not sure.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. As explained above, the issue is a result of the nature of the projection, not just an artifact of a specific implementation of the projection. And there is no way to avoid projection if what you're looking for is the screen coordinates of the point. They are, by definition, the projected coordinates. So I don't see how a "manual" projection can possibly resolve the issue here. No matter how you do your "manual" projection, you will have to divide by z one way or another. Otherwise, whatever you get will not be the desired projection…

Comment: @Robert I added an additional note to my answer above due to the discussion here…

Comment: I'm referring to manual projection via article above... point's coordinates mirrored. Need to make the point z-coordinate positive which reversing its sign at the time that the projected point's coordinates are computed: P′.x=Pcamera.x−Pcamera.z P′.y=Pcamera.y−Pcamera.z.To summarize: points in a scene are defined in the world coordinate space. However to project them onto the surface of the canvas, we first need to convert the 3D point coordinates from world space to camera space. This can be done by multiplying the point world coordinates by the inverse of the camera-to-wold matrix. Still @ w

Comment: The article you're referring to is using a right-handed world and camera coordinate system. In Direct3D, it is more common to use a left-handed system with the camera-space z-axis pointing into the screen rather than out of the screen. If you're using a left-handed system, there is no need to flip the z-axis because it is already pointing in the right direction. If you're using a right-handed system with the z-axis pointing out of the screen, then you indeed have to flip the z-coordinate in the projection like done in the article…

Comment: @Robert I would like to point out that nothing of this is relevant if you simply use the same world-view-projection matrix that you use for drawing stuff to also compute your projected point. Doing so will ensure that the results of your computation are always consistent with what is drawn by Direct3D. All you need to do is transform the point with the world-view-projection matrix like you already do in the code posted in your original posting above. If you then only draw your text when the point is in front of the camera (see my answer above for that), everything should work just fine…

Answer (score 0):

Michael's response was very helpful in making me continue down a path that the solution should be a simple comparison.  In my case, I had to re-evaluate the screen coordinates by only applying the World transform, versus the full WorldViewProjection. I call this TargetTransformed. My comparison value was then simply the Eye/Camera location (this never gets adjusted (except zoom) as the world is transformed around the Eye.)  And again note my Camera in this case is at -3.5,0,0 looking at 0,0,0 (center of model, really 8,0,0 thus a line through the center).  So I had to compare the x component, not the z component.  I add a bit of fudge .1F as the mirror artifact happens when the target is significantly behind the camera.  In which case I return the final screenCoord locations translated (-8000) way out in outer space as to guarantee they are not seen in the viewport.

```
if ((Eye.x + 0.1F) > TargetTransformed.x) 
{
    screenCoord.x += -8000;
    screenCoord.y += -8000;
    //TRACE("point is behind camera.\n");
    *psx = screenCoord.x;
    *psy = screenCoord.y;
}
else
{
    *psx = screenCoord.x;
    *psy = screenCoord.y;
}
```

And for completeness, my project has 2 view models: a) looking along a line through the center of the model. Which this can be translated to look from any direction and offset by screen x and y.  The first view model works fine with this above code.  The second view model b) targets the camera to look at a focal point of the model and then allows full rotation around that random point (not the center of the model) which requires calculating a tricky additional translation matrix and vector I call TargetViewTranslation. And for this additional translation, the formula adds the z component of the additional transform.

```
if ((Eye.x + 0.1F - m_structTargetViewTranslation.Z) > TargetTransformed.x) 
{
    screenCoord.x += -8000;
    screenCoord.y += -8000;
    //TRACE("point is behind camera.\n");
    *psx = screenCoord.x;
    *psy = screenCoord.y;
}
else
{
    *psx = screenCoord.x;
    *psy = screenCoord.y;
}
```

And success, my mirrored text problem is resolved.  Hopefully this helps others with this mirrored text problem.  Realizing that one may need to only transform the test case by the World transform, and it should be a simple comparison, and the location of the camera may impact which x or z component is used.  And if you are translating the world in any additional ways, then this translation could also impact if x or z is compared.  Using TRACE and looking at the x y z values was helpful in figuring out what components I needed to use in my specific case.